# Bash: if (command) |(command)

Tags: bash, syntax, conditional-statements

I know that the following command returns 0 (true) or 1 (false) in the following conditions:

```
hdparm -C /dev/sda |grep "active/idle"
```

true if the disk is active, false otherwise. I'd like to programmatically use this result to display another text or use it for monitoring. I've tried with this, but it doesn't work (syntax error):

```
if [ hdparm -C /dev/sda |grep "active/idle" ]; then
    echo sda1 is ON
else
    echo sda1 is OFF
fi
```

How does it work correctly?

Also, is there a clearly understandable, definitive guide on Bash conditional expressions somewhere that would explain all the different kinds of expression statements for every possible situation?

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ Try this page

Answer (score 3):

I usually just simply use

```
if hdparm -C /dev/sda | grep -q 'active/idle' ; then
    echo sda1 is ON
else
    echo sda1 id OFF
fi
```

Comment: @LonelyPixel, when you realize than `[` and `[[` are just commands, not special `if` syntax, and that `if` acts on the exit status of that command, this answer will be more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the conditional statement inside a subshell:

```
if [ -z "$(hdparm -C /dev/sda |grep "active/idle")" ]; then
```

`-z` tests the empty string here. Probably you also have to replace `active/idle` with `active`.

EDIT: as @abasu suggests, in this case, it's better to test for the return code of grep, which will be 0 if the expression was matched:

```
hdparm -C /dev/sda | grep -q "active/idle"
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 0]; then
```

You will find all details on conditional statements on [test man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/test.1.html). However, your shell may expand the syntax further, like bash does.

Comment: this is extremely risky. Why i would check a string which might contain something from stderr, or stdout? what if i use `grep -q`? Always use `$?` to get the result of the last command.